# How big do the holes need to be in a Zapap style Mash/Lauter Tun?

Tags: equipment, mash-tun, diy

I'm looking to make one of the mash tuns out of a plastic bucket.  I find instructions like "drill a bazillion holes into the bottom with a small drill bit".  How small?  Is there a size that's too small and likely to get clogged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Papazian indicated 1/8th inch holes.

Comment: Yeah, I did mine with 1/8 inch and worked beautifully.  I think I went through a six pack of brew while I was drilling though, it took forever.